# Can we use Databricks Pool with Interactive cluster in Azure

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Can we use Databricks Pool with Interactive cluster in Azure. I tried to look in databricks docs, but not able to find any details.

Link: https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/instance-pools/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it for interactive clusters as well - see [this section](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/instance-pools/cluster-instance-pool.html#attach-a-cluster-to-a-pool) of documentation that shows that.

[image]